# Problems deserializing using Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int studentNumber;
    public string testWeek;
    public string topics;
}
```

I do some stuff to it, serialize it and save it in a file. It looks likes this:

```
[
  {
    "studentNumber": 1,
    "testWeek": "1",
    "topics": "5 & 8"
  },
  {
    "studentNumber": 2,
    "testWeek": "1",
    "topics": "5 & 8"
  },
  {
    "studentNumber": 3,
    "testWeek": "1",
    "topics": "5 & 8"
  },
  {
    "studentNumber": 4,
    "testWeek": "1",
    "topics": "5 & 8"
  },
  {
    "studentNumber": 5,
    "testWeek": "1",
    "topics": "5 & 8"
  }
]
```

Later I want to deserialize it so I can work on it again. I have this code

```
Student[] arr = new Student[numberOfStudentsInClass];
arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(File.ReadAllText(_selectedClass))
```

Where _selectedClass is string containing the file name. But I am getting an error

> Cannot convert WindowsFormApplicationsForm1.Form.Student to WindowsFormApplicationsForm1.Form.Student[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception states, the method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>` returns an object of type `Student`, while the variable `arr` is of type `Student[]` .so you can't assign the result of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>` to `arr`.

you need to Deserialize your text to a `List<Student>` instead and call `.ToArray` if you want an array such as follows:

```
Student[] students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(File.ReadAllText(_selectedClass)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

You indicated in your JsonConvert.DeserializeObject that you are trying to deserialize to a single `Student` instance. Not an array. And there's no need to initialize the array in one statement and then assign it a value on another. And anyways, we generally use generic arrays these days.

Replace:

```
Student[] arr = new Student[numberOfStudentsInClass];
arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(File.ReadAllText(_selectedClass))
```

With this:

```
List<Student> students = 
     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(File.ReadAllText(_selectedClass));
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd previously been working on the data as an array but maybe as a list might be better. Time to start rewriting!